# "app.use() requires a middleware function" error while using Sequelize and Express

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

This error happens when I add this function to the aparelhos.js file:

```
function findAparelho(req, res) {
    Aparelho.findByPk(req.params.id).then((result) => res.json(result))
}
```

I suspect that the issue might be the req.params.id statement, but I have no clue if that's the case. If I remove this function, the code works perfectly. I'm getting this error on this file (app.js):

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import { sequelize } from './sequel.js'
import routes from './routes.js'

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(routes)

// Testando conexão do banco de dados
sequelize.sync(() => console.log("Banco de dados conectado"))

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 8081')
})
```

This is the routes.js file:

```
import express from "express"
import aparelhos from "./controllers/aparelho.js"

const routes = express.Router()

routes.get("/aparelhos", aparelhos.findAll)
routes.get("/aparelhos/:id", aparelhos.findAparelho)

export default { routes }
```

Aparelho.js:

```
import Aparelho from '../models/aparelhoModel.js'

function findAll(req, res) {
    Aparelho.findAll().then((result) => res.json(result))
}

function findAparelho(req, res) {
    Aparelho.findByPk(req.params.id).then((result) => res.json(result))
}

export default { findAll, findAparelho }
```

The aparelhoModel.js file looks like this:

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../sequel.js'


const Aparelho = sequelize.define('Aparelho', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    tipo: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

Aparelho.sync({ force: false })

console.log(Aparelho === sequelize.models.Aparelho)

export default Aparelho
```

The entire error code is:

```
/home/raphael/Projetos/eletroinfoOS/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
          ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (/home/raphael/Projetos/eletroinfoOS/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:11)
    at file:///home/raphael/Projetos/eletroinfoOS/server/src/app.js:13:5
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import { routes } from './routes.js'` instead of `import routes from './routes.js'`?

Comment: There's a ton of ways to do this but looking at your code just now. **1**. Delete `export default { routes }` **2.** Change `const routes = express.Router()` to `export const routes = express.Router()`

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
```

measure that you are not passing a function to `app.use()` in a place where it expects a function.  In your particular code example, I assume that would be this line of code:

```
app.use(routes)
```

If that is the line of code, then it appears that `routes` is not a function.  Since you're getting it from this:

```
import routes from './routes.js'
```

then, you apparently aren't exporting a function from './routes.js' and when we look at that, we see this:

```
export default { routes }
```

which shows you're exporting an object, not a function.  You can fix that by changing either the import or the export.  For example, you can just make the import and export more explicit (no wrapping in an object):

```
export routes

import { routes } from './routes.js'
```

so they match up and give you the actual router you want to pass to `app.use()`.

Answer (score 0):

In routes.js, you are exporting the routes object inside an object:

```
export default { routes };
```

But in app.js, you are trying to use it as if it were a default export. Instead, you should match the import statement with the export style. There are two ways to fix this:

You have to do:
Option 1: Change the Import in `app.js`. You can destructure the import to match the export:

In `app.js`:

```
import { routes } from './routes.js';
```

Option 2: Change the Export in `routes.js`. Alternatively, you can change the export statement in `routes.js` to a default export:

In `routes.js`:

```
export default routes;
```

And keep the import in `app.js` as is:

```
import routes from './routes.js';
```